# Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 21, 144 y sizes: 21

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, recurrent-neural-network

Well, i was trying to do a RNN model who makes relation of 3 things, a csv who was a worker and their 23 abilities. another when is proyects who has the the same 23 abilities but like requirements. and a distribution (i called repartition) who is a middle table of those 2 who puts rows of workers and columns of proyects.
the csv of workers is for 21 workers with their 23 abilities, with proyects is 144 proyecs with those same requirements. and the distribution is a 21x144 who shows what workers can work in those proyects with an 1 or 0
Now i tried to make a model who can process this and almost everything was going well but i can fit the model

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

workers_df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/trabajadores_si.csv', sep=';')
tasks_df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/requerimientos_si.csv', sep=';')
reparticion_df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/reparticion_si.csv', sep=';')

worker_skills = workers_df.iloc[:, 1:24].values
task_requirements = tasks_df.iloc[:, 1:24].values
reparticion_df = reparticion_df.set_index('Trabajador_ID')
reparticion = reparticion_df.values

worker_skills = worker_skills.reshape((worker_skills.shape[0], worker_skills.shape[1], 1))
task_requirements = task_requirements.reshape((task_requirements.shape[0], task_requirements.shape[1], 1))
reparticion = reparticion.reshape((reparticion.shape[0], reparticion.shape[1], 1))

reparticion = reparticion.reshape((reparticion.shape[0], reparticion.shape[1], 1))

input_worker = Input(shape=(worker_skills.shape[1], 1), name='input_worker')
input_task = Input(shape=(task_requirements.shape[1], 1), name='input_task')

lstm_layer_worker = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(input_worker)
lstm_layer_task = LSTM(64, return_sequences=False)(input_task)

concatenated = Concatenate()([lstm_layer_worker, lstm_layer_task])

output_layer = Dense(reparticion.shape[1], activation='sigmoid', name='output')(concatenated)

model = Model(inputs=[input_worker, input_task], outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

in this last one shows this error
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
x sizes: 21, 144
y sizes: 21
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.

i tried to fix the dimentions but still doesnt work
the dimentions are like this
worker_skills: (21, 23, 1)
task_requirements: (144, 23, 1)
reparticion: (21, 144, 1)
I want the model to recognize the two dimentions of the reparticion csv

Comment: can you confirm that _"all arrays contain the same number of samples"_ ?